# Why it won't open function on list event itemPress, in UI5?

Tags: sapui5

I have an object list imported, and at pressing on an element of that list I need to open a dialog, but it never calls the function

I tried to make the event on the ObjectListItem, but no result

```
'List id="sweetsList"  mode="SingleSelectMaster"  headerText="Header" 
 footerText=""  backgroundDesign="Solid" showSeparators="All" growing="true" growingThreshold="20" growingScrollToLoad="true" visible="true" itemPress="_onObjectListItemPress " items="{path:'SweetListSet', templateShareable:true}"

''ObjectListItem intro="{local>Id}" title="{local>Name}" number="" numberUnit=""  numberState="None" type="Active" selected="false" showMarkers="false""

_onObjectListItemPress: function(oEvent) {

            var sDialogName = "GuestSweetDet";
            this.mDialogs = this.mDialogs || {};
            var oDialog = this.mDialogs[sDialogName];
            if (!oDialog) {
                oDialog = new GuestSweetDet(this.getView());
                this.mDialogs[sDialogName] = oDialog;

                // For navigation.
                oDialog.setRouter(this.oRouter);
            }

            var context = oEvent.getParameter("listItem").getBindingContext();
            oDialog._oControl.setBindingContext(context);

            oDialog.open();

        },
```

Answer (score 0):

i am bit confusig.. but i think you want it like this: `itemPress` you delete and you need to put the `press` in the ObjectListitem like

`ObjectListItem intro="{local>Id}" title="{local>Name}" number="" numberUnit="" numberState="None" type="Active" selected="false" showMarkers="false" press="_onObjectListItemPress"`